# How does server.xml get generated through ant task?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a basic question to be answered for my understanding

When I execute 'ant -f configure-liberty-mysql.xml' I want to understand, how 'server.xml' is getting generated ?  Because I could not find any reference for 'server.xml' in 'configure*.xml' sample file

Answer (score 0):

Server.xml is part of the of the Liberty server instance you have manually created on your own before using the Configuration Tool that IBM MobileFirst provides.